# If $\frac {\sin A + \tan A}{\cos A}=9$, find the value of $\sin A$.

Tags: trigonometry

If $\dfrac {\sin A + \tan A}{\cos A}=9$, find the value of $\sin A$.

My Attempt:
$$\dfrac {\sin A+\tan A}{\cos A}=9$$
$$\dfrac {\sin A+ \dfrac {\sin A}{\cos A}}{\cos A}=9$$
$$\dfrac {\sin A.\cos A+\sin A}{\cos^2 A}=9$$
$$\dfrac {\sin A(1+\cos A)}{\cos^2 A}=9$$
$$\tan A.\sec A(1+\cos A)=9$$
$$\tan A(1+\sec A)=9$$

How do I go further?

Comment: Using tan=sin/cos and cos^2+sin^2=1 we get the left hand side as a rational function of sinA . Solve appropriately.

Comment: square the last expression and you know $\sec^2 x -\tan^2 x=1$

Comment: For some intuition, try plotting that function. You can see where about the answer(s) lay.

Comment: Solution of this problem is always be solution of a polynomial equation with degree $4$, and number of roots is $2$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:   using the [tangent half-angle formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula), let $\,t=\tan(A/2)\,$, then the equation becomes:

$$
\frac{2t}{1+t^2} + \frac{2t}{1-t^2}=9 \,\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \;\;\iff\;\; 9 t^4 - 18 t^2 - 4 t + 9 = 0
$$

The quartic has $2$ real roots which can be [solved in radicals](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9+t%5E4+-+18+t%5E2+-+4+t+%2B+9+%3D+0), but the calculations are not pretty.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  Once $\,t\,$ is determined, $\,\sin A = 2t/(1+t^2)\,$ follows. Or, to determine $\,x = \sin A\,$ directly, one can eliminate $t$ between the equation above and $\,(1+t^2)x-2t=0\,$ using [resultants](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B+9+t%5E4+-+18+t%5E2+-+4+t+%2B+9,+(1%2Bt%5E2)+x+-+2t,+t+%5D):

$$
1312 x^4 + 288 x^3 - 2592 x^2 - 288 x + 1296 = 0 \;\;\iff\;\; 82 x^4 + 18 x^3 - 162 x^2 - 18 x + 81 = 0
$$

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.

Comment: I don't want to upvote this but why is it downvoted? Solution of this problem is always be solution of a polynomial equation with degree $4$, and number of roots is $2$.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I like Alephnull's direct approach better, since (1) the question explicitly asks for values of sin(A), and (2) I find relating cos(A) to sin(A) much easier than remembering those tangent half-angle formulas.

Comment: @TMM In the end one gets the same equation in $\,\sin A\,$, which I added at the end of the answer. As for the half-tangent formulas, that's a matter of preference of course, but I find them quite useful to remember.

Comment: @YujieZha I can see that (it takes 10k rep to see deleted answers, I think), and that was quite petty behavior, indeed. As for the downvotes you got, I believe MSE has some safeguards against retaliatory downvoting, so they may get reversed automatically, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/serial-voting/info) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/when-are-serial-downvotes-classified-as-anomalous-what-to-do-about-a-sequence-o) for example.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for your support!

Comment: @dxiv. It is funny to see how easier it to numerically solve your first quartic compared to the second.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Indeed, interesting analysis in your other post.

Answer (score 3):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Trigonometry we have:

$$\tag {*} \sin^2x+\cos^2x=1 \Rightarrow \cos x=\sqrt {1-\sin^2x}$$

Now:

$$\frac {\sin A + \tan A}{\cos A}=9$$
$$\frac {\sin A + \frac {\sin A}{cos A}}{\sqrt {1-\sin^2A}}=9$$
$$\frac {\sin A + \frac {\sin A}{\sqrt {1-\sin^2A}}}{\sqrt {1-\sin^2A}}=9$$

Let $\sin A=x$. Thus:

$$\frac {x+ \frac {x}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}=9$$
$$x+ \frac {x}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}=9 \sqrt {1-x^2}$$
$$x\sqrt {1-x^2}+x=9(1-x^2)$$
$$x\sqrt {1-x^2}=9(1-x^2)-x$$
$$x^2(1-x^2)=81(1-x^2)^2-18x(1-x^2)+x^2$$
$$x^2-x^4=81x^4-162x^2+81-18x+18x^3+x^2$$
$$82x^4+18x^3-162x^2-18x+81=0$$

Solve the equation and we are done

Answer (score 1):

*This is too long for a comment.*

Looking at dxiv's answer, it seems to me that the "best" (because of conditionning) equation to solve is the first one, that is to say : find the zeros of
$$f(t)=9 t^4 - 18 t^2 - 4 t + 9 $$

By inspection, there is a root in $(0,1)$ and another one in $(1,2)$. So, let us apply Newton method starting at the mid point of each interval. The successive iterates will be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & t_n \\
 0 & 0.5000000000 \\
 1 & 0.6750000000 \\
 2 & 0.6730901940 \\
 3 & 0.6730915802
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & t_n \\
 0 & 1.500000000 \\
 1 & 1.373031496 \\
 2 & 1.333783223 \\
 3 & 1.330007479 \\
 4 & 1.329973644 \\
 5 & 1.329973642
\end{array}
\right)$$ which are the solutions for ten significant figures.

This makes $$A_1=1.18487\qquad A_2=1.85217$$  $$\sin(A_1)=0.926452 \qquad \sin(A_2)=0.960676$$

**Added for your curiosity**

Considering the function $$f(A)=\dfrac {\sin A + \tan A}{\cos A}-9$$ since $\cos(A)$ cannot be zero, multiply everything by $\cos^2(A)$ to get $$g(A)=\sin (A)+\sin (A) \cos (A)-9 \cos ^2(A)$$ A look at the plot of this function (which does show anymore discontinuity) reveals that the solution is close to $\frac \pi 2$. So, let $A=B+\frac \pi 2$ and consider $$h(B)=-\sin (2 B)+2 \cos (B)+9 \cos (2 B)-9$$ where the solution $B$ would be close to zero. Expanding as Taylor series $$h(B)=2-2 B-19 B^2+O\left(B^3\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, solving the quadratic leads to $$B_{\pm}=\frac{1}{19} \left(\pm\sqrt{39}-1\right)$$ leading to  $$\sin(A_1)\approx 0.928176 \qquad \sin(A_2)\approx 0.962139$$ which are quite close to the exact solutions.

We could even do much better using Padé approximants and get $$h(B)\approx \frac {2-\frac{2103 }{1091}B-\frac{120623 }{6546}B^2 } {1+\frac{79 }{2182}B+\frac{4225 }{13092}B^2 }$$ Solving the quadratic in numerator, the solutions are $$B_{\pm}=\frac{\pm\sqrt{1618999797}-6309}{120623}$$ leading to  $$\sin(A_1)\approx 0.926468 \qquad \sin(A_2)\approx 0.960703$$ closer  to the exact solutions.